# How I can save a "list" of globally or at least instance it for use in any activity, in Android?

Tags: java, android, singleton, instance

I create a class called  `Singleton` which contains a list and instance

```
public class  Singleton {
private static Singleton instance;
private List<MaterialModel> list = new ArrayList<MaterialModel>();

public Singleton(){
}

public List<MaterialModel> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<MaterialModel> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new Singleton();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void addElement(MaterialModel material){
    this.list.add(material);
}

public MaterialModel getElement(int pos){
    return this.list.get(pos);
}

public boolean foundElement(MaterialModel material){
    if(this.list.contains(material)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


}
```

The idea is to store items on the list and get them in any activity. In reality I'm trying to get this list can be used in any kind and do not lose items within it.

**First activity**

```
public class FirstActivity extends SherlockActivity{
    Singleton singleton;
        ...
       public onCreate(...){
       singleton.addElement(obj)); // MaterialModel obj = new MaterialModel(.....)
```

**Second Activty**

```
public class SecondActivity extends SherlockActivity{
        Singleton singleton;
            ...
           public onCreate(...){
           MaterialModel tmp = singleton.getElement(0)); // getElement return "obj"
```

The problem is that does not work, how can I fix it or **at least save the list globaly so that it can be used in any activity**?

Comment: is the singleton instantiated?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I dont know... but I think it isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand the idea behind the 'singleton' pattern.

Firstly, don't create a `public` constructor - instead (as Rod_Algonquin) suggests you need to use a `static` method (usually called `getInstance`) to return the single instance of the singleton.

Example...

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton mInstance = null;

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null)
            mInstance = new Singleton();
        return mInstance;
    }

    // Other code here

}
```

In the above code the singleton class holds a reference to a single instance of itself as `mInstance`. To start with `mInstance` is `null` and as there is no public constructor, it's not possible to create a new instance of the singleton from another class by using `new Singleton()` but it is possible from within the singleton itself.

Instead, whenever you need to access your singleon use...

```
Singleton.getInstance();
```

If you look at the code for `getInstance()` you'll see...

```
if (mInstance == null)
    mInstance = new Singleton();
return mInstance;
```

Obviously the first time `getInstance()` is called `mInstance` will be `null` so the `if` condition will be true and the line `mInstance = new Singleton()` will be executed. Following that, the method will return the instance referenced by `mInstance`.

On any subsequent calls to `Singleton.getInstance()` from any class or method in your code, `mInstance` will already be instantiated and therefore the `if` condition will be false but the `getInstance` method will still return `mInstance` as the single instance of the singleton.

As an added bonus you can either hold a reference to the singleton in your code and call a method such as...

```
Singleton theSingleton = Singleton.getInstance();
theSingleton.doSomething();
```

...or you can simply use it to chain a call to a public method in the singleton such as...

```
Singleton.getInstance().doSomething();
```

So for your first `Activity` you can do this...

```
Singleton.getInstance().addElement(obj);
```

...and for your second `Activity` do this...

```
MaterialModel tmp = Singleton.getInstance().getElement(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the instance first of your `Singleton` before modifying any data in it.

**example:**

every time you call the `Singleton singleton` you need to call the static instance of it and instantiate in your `Singleton` object;

```
Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
```